# Save composite key data to elastic search document

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, composite-key

I am using hibernate envers to audit the data for my tables and save in Oracle DB. This auditing data I am reading and saving to elastic search index through Java code using spring data elastic search. I have a composite key (id and rev) which defines a unique row to save data but for elastic search I can't provide a composite key. It is taking only rev (identifier) column and replacing data.

Hibernate envers background information:
rev is the default identifier that hibernate is providing and for list of records which modified at same time, it creates same rev id:

```
Eg: id    rev    comments
     1     1      newly created
     2     1      newly created
     1     2      modified
     2     2      modified
```

First 2 rows are created at same time and next time I modified both the rows and updated so hibernate envers creates same rev id for 1 save.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MyEmbeddedId.class)
@Document(indexName = "#{@indexName}", type = "my-document", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
@Getter @Setter
public class MyClassAudit {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id --> (this is for elastic search _id)
    private Long rev;
}

@Getter @Setter
public class MyEmbeddedId implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Long rev;
}
```

Java code:

```java
List<MyClass> list = repository.findById(id);
elasticSearchRepository.saveAll(list)
```

Elastic search repository interface:

```java
public interface MyElasticSearchRepository extends GenericSearchRepository<MyClassAudit, Long> {}
```

When I save data to elastic search then all 4 records should be saved as given in example but only 2 records are saved like below:

```
_id    id    rev    comments
  1     2     1      newly created
  2     2     2      modified
```

It is because rev is taken as identifier in elastic search and 2nd record is being updated.

How to make elastic search to consider composite key to maintain unique records?
PS: _id is the elastic search identifier. since rev is having spring data annotation id, rev is considered as identifier in elastic search

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch itself has no concept of a composite key. Spring Data Elasticsearch takes the `@Id` annotated element and uses it's `toString()` method to create the id entry for Elasticsearch (and stores the field as well in the source).

So - without haven't tried - you could use your `MyEmbeddedId` class as a field property of your `MyClassAudit` class and annotate it with `@Id`. But you have to have this property in your class, it will not be synthesized.

This will probably conflict with the annotations for hibernate, but I don't think it's a good idea to share one entity between storages and using mixed annotations.

Comment: Thank you fro your answer. I tried this approach but it will throw ClassCastException because spring data elastic search repository interface provides Id as in below and do not accept MyEmbeddedId type.
ElasticsearchRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>

Comment: can you post the exception stacktrace? which class cannot be cast into what?

Comment: MyEmbeddedId Object cannot cast to ID.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ID type class com.example.MyEmbeddedId
 at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryBaseClass(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:90)

Comment: solved it having id concatenate with composite key like below:                 `@Transient
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    private Long id; `                                                                                                           and setting id with java code which concatenates composite key: obj.setId(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(id)+String.valueOf(rev)));